# Check date for null

Tags: java

I want to check if date from database is empty like this:

```
private boolean hasAccountExpired(LocalDateTime password_changed_at) {

        return password_changed_at.isEqual(null);
}
```

But I get NPE. What is the proper way to check if date field from database is empty?

Comment: `password_changed_at == null` ?

Comment: `if (Optional.ofNullable(password_changed_at).isPresent()) { ... }` `</irony>`

Comment: As an aside: it is convention to use [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for naming variables

Answer (score 1):

`password_changed_at == null` will tell you if it's null.

However, this doesn't necessarily tell you if it's *empty* in the database - that depends on your implementation.